# Bootstrap Multi Item Carousel not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a multi item carousel that displays 6 items when on a wider screen but continues to show 6 items on smaller screens. It just stacks them on top of each other and overlaps other content. I want to show 4 items on small screens, then 2 items on extra small. I have adapted the code from this codepen: https://codepen.io/MhSami/pen/zNBMbj, and I found this more responsive codepen (https://codepen.io/Qvatra/pen/yOvBoM) with 4 items, but, when I try to change my code to it, it just doesn't display at all.

[My current problem with the stacking of the items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpKKU.png)

[When I try to change my code to the responsive carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31IFy.png)

Heres the html for the carousel

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:white; height:140px; padding-top:15px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-md-12 col-centered">
                    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3500" id="myCarousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                    <div>
                                        <a href="{% url 'category-2' category2='arsenal' %}">
                                            <img src="{% static 'logo/arsenal_city_logo.png' %}" class="img-responsive" style="max-width:100px; max-height:110px">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                    <a href="{% url 'category-2' category2='man_united' %}">
                                        <img src="{% static 'logo/manchester_united_fc_logo.png' %}" class="img-responsive" style="max-width:100px; max-height:110px">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                    <a href="{% url 'category-2' category2='fcb' %}">
                                        <img src="{% static 'logo/barcelona_logo.png' %}" class="img-responsive" style="max-width:100px; max-height:110px">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                    <a href="{% url 'category-2' category2='chelsea' %}">
                                        <img src="{% static 'logo/chelsea_logo.png' %}" class="img-responsive" style="max-width:100px; max-height:110px">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                    <a href="{% url 'category-2' category2='everton' %}">
                                        <img src="{% static 'logo/everton_fc_logo.png' %}" class="img-responsive" style="max-width:100px; max-height:110px">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                    <a href="{% url 'category-2' category2='liverpool' %}">
                                        <img src="{% static 'logo/liverpool_fc_logo.png' %}" class="img-responsive" style="max-width:100px; max-height:110px">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner { margin: auto; width: 90%; }
.carousel-control            { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
  background-image:none;
}
 
.glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  margin-top:-10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  color: #444;
}

.carousel-inner {
  a {
    display:table-cell;
    height: 180px;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  img {
    max-height: 150px;
    margin: auto auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px ) {

  .carousel-inner > .item.next,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
      left: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(16.7%, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(16.7%, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
      left: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-16.7%, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(-16.7%, 0, 0);
  }

}


@media (max-width: 992px ) {

    .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
    }

    .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

What I've tried:

- Changing the code to the responsive codepen with no success
- Changing the transform values for the various screen sizes. You can see the final media css block for when 4 items should be showing.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide this as a snippet and simplify it a bit? There's a lot of code in there and things like the href's and the image src's aren't going to work outside of your environment.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem. It turns out that I was importing the scripts in the wrong order for the responsive codepen. For future reference, what should I be posting instead of the whole block of code?
Edit: I posted the solution but I can't accept it as an answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can post Snippets. You can find the Snippet button in the WYSIWYG editor that appears when you create the question (It's the opposing chevrons button). Also try to simplify the code to remove things which aren't causing the problem. (e.g. non working hrefs) Obviously make sure the Snippet still replicates the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was importing the scripts in the wrong order which is why the responsive codepen didn't work in my environment